# Is there an equivalent of filterBounds() function for images in google earth engine (other than clip images)?

Tags: raster, google-earth-engine, clip

I wanted to restrict my raster to an ROI. clip() function gives pixels outside the ROI masked with zero pixel value. Is there any way to do the same thing that filterbounds() does on an image?

Comment: Can you provide an example for us to work with? You could consider applying selfMask() after clipping your image, not sure if that is what you are looking for.